# Can the drive API be used to upload notebooks for use in colaboratory?

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory

The examples in [External data: Drive, Sheets, and Cloud Storage](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb) show how to work with plain drive files, authenticated with the assistance of `google.colab`. Could I use something similar to post my notebooks from non-colaboratory over to colaboratory?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible to use the Drive Python API to upload Colab notebooks. (The google.colab auth module is a convenience wrapper to obtain OAuth credentials.)

But, Colab and Jupyter share the same JSON file format. So, the easiest thing to do is to just upload the files to Drive directly, e.g., using the web UI or the [desktop sync client](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/).

You can also upload a notebook by selecting 'Upload notebook' in the File menu of the Colab web app.

[Here's an example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=0B7I8C_4vGdF6V0ZJQVBMVVp4LVk) I created in Jupyter which uploads itself to Drive using gcloud and standard Drive APIs. (The libraries needed are pip-installed in the notebook if you don't have them.)

Comment: My curiosity was mostly for automation around my current notebooks, pushing out my working copies from JupyterHub to colaboratory.

Comment: Ah, got it. [Here's an example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=0B7I8C_4vGdF6V0ZJQVBMVVp4LVk) I created in Jupyter which uploads itself to Drive using `gcloud` and standard Drive APIs. (The libraries needed are `pip`-installed in the notebook if you don't have them.)